# Xamarin Form iOS - Distribute app Long Path Problem

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I tried to distribute my app to app store using visual studio 2019.
I faced the following issue

[image]

Does anybody know how to overcome this without shortening the paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a turn around for this problem using Xcode, as follows

1. After you successfully archived your project in Visual Studio go to Xcode in Mac
2. Go to Window --> Organizer
3. There in Archives you can find your archived project.
4. Select that project and distribute it to App Store.

Enjoy!

Comment: @It seems that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.